# JPlayer issue in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jplayer

i think there is a problem in jquery.jplayer.min.js file which one i am using.

My jplayer is not working in only IE9.

its working in all other browser.

Comment: If every other browser is working, then it's probably a problem with IE9, not jPlayer.

Answer (score 5):

In [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/browse_thread/thread/2ac40b4157729017/0f364d77ac848eb9?lnk=gst&q=ie9#0f364d77ac848eb9) Mark P. notes that you must have MIME types set properly.  Try putting this in your .htaccess:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/mp4 m4v
```

More here:
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response

Comment: I had my mime types set to video/mpeg which worked fine for every browser but IE9. Switched to video/mp4 for both extensions and now golden.

Comment: +1 for this. We set the headers in S3 and the videos work. Annoying as heck since there's no way we will remember to do this. So -1 for jPlayer itself.

Answer (score 2):

The current major release (2.0.0) [does not support IE9](http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/msg/17e445dc6d6c2ba0), but support is being added [as of version 2.0.8 (github)](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer).

Comment: I am using 2.1.0 and no music is played in IE9. I tryied .mp3, .m4a, and .ogg. Is there a way to force the flash player in IE9?

Answer (score 2):

Put this line of code at the very beginning of your document.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`
It forces IE9 to work under standard document mode.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705

Comment: No need to make page html5 as the I've got it working fine in XHTML (of course, specify a doctype, but that goes without saying). Turns out for me that IE9 is particular that the mime type be video/mp4 not video/mpeg (the latter worked fine for all other browsers).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by forcing IE9 to use Flash instead of html5.

```
jPlayer({
    "solution": navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5")>-1 ? "flash" : "html,flash"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is IE9 like always jaa, try playing ogg files or m4a and that works