# jPlayer issue for mp3 with IE : any recommendation?

Tags: python, django, internet-explorer, mp3, jplayer

I have a django website which make possible to listen mp3 files with jPlayer.

It works ok on Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE9. However, it is ok when running the site locally with the django dev server.

Is there any things, i should be careful on server side. I've checked than the jPlayer.swf is on the server. Any thing else?

Any recommendation for debugging this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search reveals similar problems about jPlayer and IE9. Have you seen this q/a before?

[JPlayer issue in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175417/jplayer-issue-in-ie9) <--

It could be as simple as an .htaccess fix. Gracias.

Comment: Yes! something wrong in htaccess: The mimetype for mp3 was not correct. It works after changing it into AddType audio/mpeg .mp3